# How to suppress gevent error message on flask server running HTTP when it gets an HTTPS request

Tags: flask, gevent

If I (or someone else) makes an HTTPS call against my "plain" flask server (expecting an HTTP request) running gevent, I get this message:

> <gevent.*socket3.socket at 0x103fd04c0 object, fd=7, family=30,
> type=1, proto=0>: (from ('::1', 50418, 0, 0)) Invalid HTTP method:
> '\x16\x03\x01\x01:\x01\x00\x016\x03\x03zGÀQÝQ0r\x0eCªðÏ\x19é!\x1dùº\x92u9\x92õ?\x0b%\x1b\x13\x00¦I
> \x01¸¨Q:â©\x86\x89¯ûo\x15õ\x07*\x8cQ\xa0Ä$\x1d\x0e&8Å\x89\x1cî$jñ\x00b\x13\x03\x13\x02\x13\x01Ì©Ì¨ÌªÀ0À,À(À$À\x14À\n'

I dont think the exception ever reaches python code so I cant catch the exception before it gets logged. Is there another way to suppress it?